# Any way to shorten String type in C++?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, shortcut

Let's say I have function `foo(string& s)`. If I would get `C string`, `foo(char* s)`, I would simply call the function as `foo("bar")`.
I wonder if I can somehow do it in the `C++ String`?

Somehow to shorten this:

```
string v("bar");
foo(v)
```

I'm using Linux GCC C++.

Comment: afaik you can do foo("bar") if the argument is a string, the conversion will be done automatically.

Comment: @Ashalynd It not working, at least in gcc

Comment: could you paste your code and the error you get?

Comment: The argument has to be a const reference.

Comment: because you are passing it by reference.

Comment: Could you fix the title so it has some relation to the question you are attempting to ask?

Comment: Observe that calling `foo2("bar")` for the definition `void foo2(char*)` is dangerous as it allows you to write to the argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not working because the argument has to be a `const` reference:

```
void foo( const std::string& s )
//        ^^^^^

foo( "bar" );  // will work now
```

Answer (score 1):

- If you want `foo` to only read from the argument you should write `foo(const string& s)`.
- If you want `foo` to save the string somewhere (a class member..) you should write `foo(string s)`.

Both versions allow you to write `foo("bar");` which would't make any sense with a non const reference.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try `foo(string("bar"));` to get your desired results, but since it is expecting a reference this wont work either.

So that means that your best bet is overloading for `const char *` to call the string method (this way you maintain only one method).

Answer (score 0):

The `std::string` class does have an implicit conversion from `const char*`, so normally, passing a string literal into a function taking `std::string` works just fine.

Why it fails in your case is that the function takes its parameter as a non-const lvalue reference, and thus it requires an actual `std::string` lvalue to operate on.

If the function actually wants to take a non-const lvalue reference (i.e. it modifies the argument), you have to create an lvalue `std::string` and pass it (just like you do).

If the function does not modify the argument, change it to take by const-reference (`const std::string&`) or by value (`std::string`) instead; for both of these, passing an rvalue (like the `std::string` created by implicit conversion from `const char*`) will work and you can thus call the function with string literals.